# Windows Server 2012 R2. C:\Windows\SYSVOL\domain contains a copy of my laptop

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

I am running Windows Server 2012R2 I have a domain set up. I use this server mostly for my own entertainment and experimentation.

I have just noticed that on the server the C:\Windows\SYSVOL\domain directory contains what seems to be a copy of my laptop some 650G of files.
I'm assuming this is some feature that I have managed to turn on!

Any idea how I can turn it off?

Searching the internet I'm not really finding anything useful but its a hard search.   I don't see anything obvious in policy's etc but I don't really know what I'm doing.  Any Assistance would be greatly appreciated.